# Preserving bash redirection in a python subprocess

Tags: python, redirect, subprocess

To begin with, I am only allowed to use python 2.4.4

I need to write a process controller in python which launches and various subprocesses monitors how they affect the environment.  Each of these subprocesses are themselves python scripts.

When executed from the unix shell, the command lines look something like this:

python myscript arg1 arg2 arg3 >output.log 2>err.log &

I am not interested in the input or the output, python does not need to process. The python program only needs to know 
1) The pid of each process
2) Whether each process is running.

And the processes run continuously.

I have tried reading in the output and just sending it out a file again but then I run into issues with readline not being asynchronous, for which there are several answers many of them very complex.

How can I a formulate a python subprocess call that preserves the bash redirection operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like what you are looking for here is to be able to launch a list of scripts with the output redirected to files.  In that case, launch each of your tasks something like this:

```
task = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'myscript', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'],
    stdout=open('output.log', 'w'), stderr=open('err.log', 'w'))
```

Doing this means that the subprocess's stdout and stderr are redirected to files that the monitoring process opened, but the monitoring process does not have to be involved in copying data around.  You can also redirect the subprocess stdins as well, if needed.

Note that you'll likely want to handle error cases and such, which aren't handled in this example.

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I took.  The only issue I remain a bit confused about is the documentation for this module. It seems to indicate that the only valid options for stdout for example is PIPE or STDOUT. There is no documentation that says I can use any file descriptor.

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor): "stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None." and "Additionally, stderr can be STDOUT".

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing file descriptors as the stdout/stderr arguments to subprocess.Popen. This should be exquivalent to running from with redirection from bash. That redirection is implemented with fdup(2) after fork and the output should never touch your program. You can probably also pass fopen('/dev/null') as a file descriptor.

Alternatively you can redirect the stdout/stderr of your controller program and pass None as stdout/stderr. Children should print to your controllers stdout/stderr without passing through python itself. This works because the children will inherit the stdin/stdout descriptors of the controller, which were redirected by bash at launch time.

Answer (score 0):

The subprocess module is good.

You can also do this on *ix with os.fork() and a periodic os.wait() with a WNOHANG.